# Solving $\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}e^{tk}q^{n}(1-q)^{k-n}\binom{k-1}{n-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, binomial-coefficients, moment-generating-functions

I am trying to find the moment generating function of a variable with a negative binomial disribution (Counuting the number of trials when the counting stops once $n$ successes, with probability $q$ each, have occurred).

I have come up with:

$$M_{X}(t)=\mathbb{E}(e^{tX})=\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}e^{tk}q^{n}(1-q)^{k-n}\binom{k-1}{n-1}$$

But am not sure how to continue.

Comment: Maybe to consider $X=Y_1+... +Y_n$ where $Y_i$ iid with geometric distribution. You calculate the MGF of the geometric distributed random variable first and then use some properties of the moment generating function... Can you figure out what to do?

Comment: @Shashi. Yes! Should have thought of that myself, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finish off by rearranging and applying the negative binomial theorem:
$$\begin{align}
M_{X}(t)=\mathbb{E}(e^{tX})&=\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}e^{tk}q^{n}(1-q)^{k-n}\binom{k-1}{n-1} \\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}e^{t(k+n)}q^{n}(1-q)^{k}\binom{k+n-1}{n-1}\\
&=e^{tn} q^n\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(e^{t}(1-q)\right)^{k}\binom{k+n-1}{k}\\
&=e^{tn} q^n (1+e^t(1-q))^{-n}\\
&=\left(\frac{qe^t}{1+e^t(1-q)}\right)^n
\end{align}$$